# Retrieving hours in 24 hour format in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, datetime

I am using this format to get hours

```
   NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"hh";
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

    NSString *date = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:now];

    NSInteger myHour = [date intValue];
```

The problem is it returns e.g `4Pm` i Want it to return `16` Instead of 4. How can I do that? I tried replacing hh by single h by of no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here Your input:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh"];
NSDate *Yourcurrenttime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:Yourstring];
```

And date converted to the String ..

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH"];
NSString *date = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:now];

NSInteger myHour = [date intValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is answer :-

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"HH";
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

    NSString *date = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

    NSInteger myHour = [date intValue];
    NSLog(@"%d",myHour);
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 1):

**Its for 12 hour time format :-**

```
NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeFormat setDateFormat:@"hh a"];
NSString *theTime = [timeFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];    
NSLog(@"time, %@",theTime);
```

**Its for 24 hour time format:-**

```
NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeFormat setDateFormat:@"HH"];
NSString *theTime = [timeFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];    
NSLog(@"time, %@",theTime);
```