# event.startDate output is null

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, eventkit

i am trying to add event to the calender, but event.startDate output is null.

```
event.startDate = [formatter dateFromString:dateandtime];
```

Can any one tell me why?

i checked the formatter, every thing is fine.. but i am not getting the event saved.

please find the code for your reference.

```
-(IBAction)ADDEvent
{

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ +-HHMM"]; // SPOT the difference in this line
    NSString *dateandtime =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.eventtime];

    EKEventStore *eventstore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
    EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore: eventstore];
    event.title     = self.eventname;
    event.startDate = [formatter dateFromString:dateandtime];
    event.endDate=[[formatter dateFromString:dateandtime] dateByAddingTimeInterval:(30*60)];
    NSLog(@"%@",[[formatter dateFromString:dateandtime] dateByAddingTimeInterval:(30*60)]);
         NSLog(@"%@",dateandtime);
    [event setCalendar:[eventstore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];

     }}
```

Comment: Don't paste huge of code..just paste the code where you have problem..

Comment: ya i did it, can you help me?

Comment: follow my ans http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740423/how-to-display-picker-view-in-mm-dd-yy-format-in-ios-5-1/12740543#12740543

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759539/retrieving-hours-in-24-hour-format-in-iphone/12760035#12760035

Answer (score 0):

You don't way what type `self.eventtime` is so it's not possible to give a definitive answer, however I can say that you're getting a `nil` because the date in `self.eventtime` is not in the format you tell the `NSDateFormatter` to expect.

I would also suggest that converting an object to a string and then to a date probably also isn't the most efficient way of doing it. Maybe `NSDateComponent` might do the same job more directly?

Comment: my self. eventtime is in the format of "Mon, 17 Dec 2012 08:00:00 CST".

Comment: What _datatype_ is it? If it's already a string, why copy it into another string?

Comment: What type is `self.eventtime`? Is it an `NSDate`? Is it an `NSString`? An `NSTimeInterval`?